# Redirecting the user to the same page after login (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, authentication

I want to redirect the user to the same page after login. The scenario is that the user will be redirected to a signin page if he is not logged in. On the signin page, when he clicks on one of the available user options, I want to store the user_id and then redirect him back to the same page where he came from.
For this, I'm using the following code:

In application_helper.rb:

```
module ApplicationHelper
def check_signed_in
if session[:user] == nil
  if request.format.html?
    session[:referer] = request.url
    redirect_to signin_index_path
  else
    @error = 'Please Signin!'
    @forward_page = '/signin'
    render 'signin/show_signin.js'
  end
end
end
end
```

In SigninController:

```
class SigninController < ApplicationController
def index
session[:user] = params[:user_id]
redirect_to session[:referer]
end 
end
```

In signin/index page:

```
We simulate a signin here. Click on an user and you will logged in as the selected user and you will be redirected the previous page.
```

`<%= link_to  'Sam', controller:"signin", action: "index" , user_id: 284542812, remote: true %>
<%= link_to  'Marge', controller:"signin", action: "index" , user_id: 604700687, remote: true %>`

Error that I'm getting:

the user_id is not being saved and while redirecting I get an error saying that session[:referer] is nil.

Please explain what am I doing wrong

Comment: When you do this: `if request.format.html?` u getting `false` cuz, in yr link_to tag calls async `remote: true`. thats why `session[:referer]` is nil.

Comment: where did you save `referrer` to session?

Comment: In the session[:referer]. It will be saved if the user is not signed in. Please take a look at application_helper.rb @Hieu Pham

Answer (score 2):

You are calling it async `if request.format.html?` then asking a format is `html?` it `returns false`. Since it `returns false` you are not able to store this session `session[:referer] = request.url`.

Also Rails has `redirect_to :back` option too. Try this below first, and let me know...

**Helper:**

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def check_signed_in
    if session[:user]
      session[:referer] = request.url
    end
  end
end
```

**Controller:**

```
class SigninController < ApplicationController
  include ApplicationHelper

  def index
    check_signed_in
    session[:user] = params[:user_id]
    redirect_to session[:referer]
  end 
end
```

Comment: Thank you. Tried it but was not working. What was happening: when I tried accessing index page, it was taking me to signin page (since I was not logged in). In signin page, it was calling previous page. And this was a recursive action and finally, it crashed. I was never able to see the signin page to choose an option. Can you please suggest some other way? Thank you!

Comment: @MouryaKoluguri i just dnt know how u implemented it. but look at this book, he had good example in forwarding the url -> `https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users` search it like `session[:forwarding_url]`.